# Is this RESTfull?

Tags: api, rest, url, routes

I'm a little confused as to what the collection URI's should return.

Say I have a collection, `/users` of decently large elements. Then we have the expected:

```
GET /users/123           // returns user element with identifier 123
```

But what should

```
GET /users
```

return? If the collection is large, and the elements are large, it's probably not a good thing to return all elements. Perhaps instead, `GET` requests at the `/users` level should return *element summaries* (identifiers and possibly a few properties), while `GET` requests at the `/users/` level should return actual elements. Then you could do something like;

```
GET /users
   > [{name: abc, id: 1}, {name: def, id: 2}, {name: ghi, id: 3}, ...]
GET /users/2
   > {name: def, prop1: *, prop2: *, ...}
```

Which could be a good way to lazily load data if you wanted to preview important application-domain properties before requesting them in their entirety. With this, in order to apply queries, you'd do something like

```
GET /users?prop1=value           // returns element summaries of elements with prop1=value
GET /users/?prop1=value          // returns elements with prop1 = value
```

Is this approach OK? Or do the other methods acting on `/users` then loose meaning.. (ex. `PUT /users` ?)

Comment: I don't like the / on the end thing. Don't know why. I'd rather use summaries when no ID supplied but allow overriding that with query parts and maybe a "?detail=yes" that you can use to get detail. Just don't call that without a query unless you want lots and lots of result bytes.

Comment: @LeeMeador Ya the / thing seems weird. The `?detail=yes` idea is a good idea - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like the style where /users does not return all users but returns information needed to then query specific users. So the summaries approach is how I would generally write it.

If you were filtering or querying, I would go with the first one you provided:

```
GET /users?prop1=value
```

I don't care for the second one

```
GET /users/?prop1=value
```

because it can be easily misunderstood or lead to confusing and unintended bugs (missing one slash still works but completely changes the results).

You might want to go with an approach of an alternative URL for returning specific users based on search parameters such as

```
GET /users?prop1=value    // returns element summaries based on results of prop1 matching
GET /users/find?prop1=value // returns elements with prop1 = value
```

Obviously your wording could change (find/search) or you could use a completely different URI but I try to avoid things where two different meanings are a single character/symbol apart to avoid unintended mistakes. Another option would be to make sure you outline this clearly in provided documentation so anyone consuming your API is alerted about this potential.

Actually expanding on this I would go with the all construct.

So instead of using find/search I would provide:

```
GET /users                   // returns summaries
GET /users/#                 // returns element
GET /users/all               // returns all elements
GET /users/all?prop1=value   // returns all elements that match the filter
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I like it. This is still considered RESTfull right?

Comment: I would argue that the URL pattern that you use has little to do with it being restful or not as long as your are consistent in your implementation. RESTful is simply an architectural style, it's not a set specification that you must implement a set URL pattern. :) As long as your system was restful in it's overall design, using this url structure does not change that fact.

Comment: Ya thats what I was thinking... thanks man - I'll probably go with just this! Appreciate the time